# Image on background sticking to fullscreen - button sticking to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I apologize if the question is simple but I barely begin in front end development and may miss some keyword to grasp existing question.

I have a simple `html` file with a title and three button, the CSS has only a picture.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="banner">

<h1> A random title </h1>

<div id="navi" class="navi">
        <a class="navi-button" href="#Home">Rules</a> &nbsp;
        <a class="navi-button" href="quizz1.html">Quizz</a> &nbsp;
        <a class="navi-button" href="#Contact"> Contact</a> &nbsp;
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
html {
    background: url(../pics/somePicture.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Problem:**

when I resize, minimze, maximize my browser window, the title and the three buttons are sticked to my left border and the image resize as well... whereas I want the button to stay on the left like when my browser window is in full screen. I want the image to be set up in full screen, and when I resize, there is only the part of the image delimited by the browser window which should appear.

For example, on [this](http://hackzurich.com/) by resizing the window, the buttons are staying on the bottom and the background image does not adapt to resizing.

I am open to jQuery solution if needed.

Many thanks for the help,

Comment: you want all the three `<a>` to be in one single line even when the browser width is resized to very low?? like this - http://jsfiddle.net/qp4xfvjj/ ?

Comment: yes, exactly, my question is both on these trhee buttons staying on a single line (and hidden if you resivze to a thin window of 1cm width) and on having a full screen image which do not adapt to the user resizing.

Comment: 'hidden if you resivze to a thin window of 1cm width' means you want to hide the buttons when window width is 1cm??

Comment: Also there is no `float:center`..

Comment: according to this line _I want the button to stay on the left_  i think you should use `float:left;` instead of `float:center;` and as you have written `float=center` this makes error it is invalid

Comment: I removed the `float:center` but I still have the same problem! The website in the link is a clear example of what I want to achieve on the button on the bottom left when you resize the window.

Comment: Unrelated, but put your `background-image` on your _body_ element, not your html element.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the image to adapt on resizing, the css should only be:

`background-image: url("../pics/somePicture.jpg");`

And the image will be showed as it is, never adapting to the window size.

About the links, the answer given by #Rohit Kumar is what you want, test it here: [jsfiddle.net/qp4xfvjj](http://jsfiddle.net/qp4xfvjj) , but may be adding:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
```

Comment: Ha, your answer is someone else answer :) Ah well, fair deuce and you've given credit where credit is due so, ... +1.

Comment: ok, this is not the desired result .. did you check the link I provided? There are 6 buttons on the bottom left in full screen. Just minimize the browser window there do not appear. On my code still yes.

Comment: this is clearly not the answer, I dunno why an upvote has been done?!

Comment: do you mean the "Home", "News" ... buttons? i see them reordering when i resize that page...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to break the `<a>` on next lines then you should use -
`white-space: nowrap;`.
And if you want to hide the `<a>` when window width is less than 1cm then you should use `@media` query like this -

```
@media all and (max-width: 100px) { /* you have to enter width in px */
    a {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp4xfvjj/2/)

And for your `background-image` to be fully displayed (without any cropping) at all resolutions, you should use - `background-size: contain` instead of `background-size: cover`